# GRUB not booting Windows 10 as expected

Tags: linux, windows-10, grub

I seem to have a strange issue with GRUB:

I have setup my computer to dual boot with Linux Mint and Windows 10, Mint works as expected and will boot every time, whereas Windows will not boot.

If I try to boot Windows 10 by highlighting it and pressing `enter` it never boots. The screen flashes and it seems like its about to boot and then I get stuck with my GRUB background image, and I have to reboot the computer.

However, when booting up the computer and reaching GRUB and I go to edit `e` the boot commands for the Windows 10 loader, and then exit via F10 without changing anything it boots up Windows as expected.

If anyone needs any other information just ask!

Comment: I've had a few oddities with `grub` dual-booting Ubuntu and Windows. The `grub` menu identifies the Windows partition, but it never boots from here. Instead, I need to select Windows from the UEFI boot menu. In your case, I wonder if it was the reboot that resolved the problem, rather than the aborted `grub` menu edit, as I've had other problems with dual-booting which I have put down to one OS leaving the hardware in a state that the other doesn't handle. Try powering off before you boot into Windows and see if this works first time. If not try restoring the Windows OS loader and adding Mint.

Comment: Cheers, I'll try this and get back to you!

Comment: @AFH So this is pretty strange, even after a reinstall of both Mint and Windows I get the same state. When rebooting and attempting to load Windows through GRUB it still doesn't boot. I'll get a flashing `_` and then black screen which requires a reboot.